# Citation showing a number is transcendental

Tags: reference-request, transcendental-numbers

On the [Wikipedia page](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Transcendental_number) about transcendental numbers
there is a claim that for $\beta > 1$, if $\alpha = \displaystyle \sum\limits_{k=0}^{\infty }10^{-\left\lfloor \beta ^{k}\right\rfloor }$ ($\beta \mapsto \lfloor \beta \rfloor$  is the floor function), then $\alpha$ is transcendental.

The wiki page doesn't cite a source proving this and I cannot find one. I would like to cite this result in a paper I'm writing.

Any help tracking down a source would be much appreciated.

Comment: If true, it seems highly unlikely to be particular to $10.$ Possibly then for integer $b\geq 2$ in place of $10.$ Certainly, it is irrational in all such cases.

Comment: This looks like a [Liouville number](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Liouville_number).